# decimal with input type=number on native browser

Tags: android, html, android-webview, number-formatting

Hy,

On my website, you have to submit a money amount(with often cents).

```
<input type="number" step="0.1"/>
```

My issue is that on some version(android 4.3, Edit : android 2.3.3) of the native android browser, the numeric pad who appear don't have the '.'

I want to keep the numeric pad for writing the amount

Any idea how I can do ?

Edit:
I prefere not having to split it.

Comment: Split it? So you have 2 input fields, where 1 is especially for cents.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the field to two different field:

```
<input type="number" name="number"/>
<input type="number" name="decimal" />
```

By submit you can add them together with:

```
$_POST['number'] . ',' . $_POST['decimal']
```

Comment: I prefere not having to split it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, in fact, not in the html nor in the browser, but in the android default keypad for the android 4.3:
the numeric version of the keypad don't allow comma

If I don't want to impact the use for the unimpacted user,
The solution would be to ask to the impacted user to switch to annother key app.
Or wait an update of the keyapp.